# Javascript: The good parts - Example in Augmenting Types

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I was basically following the example on **JavaScript: The Good Parts**, says (on page 49):

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

Number.method('integer', function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
});

document.writeln((-10 / 3).integer()); // -3
```

But I got an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Math[(intermediate value)(intermediate
>   value)(intermediate value)] is not a function

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `ceil` not `ceiling`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. Is it a typo on the book?